# Mysql database starts using alot of CPU after some period of time

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci

innodb_file_per_table=ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
aria_pagecache_buffer_size = 2000M
max_connections = 150
max_allowed_packet=500M

tmp_table_size = 64M (was 16M before)

slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mariadb/slow-query.log
```

---

I have 20GB of RAM, and Raid HDD on my Centos server. I have php-fpm, nginx and mariadb configuration. When I reboot mariadb service the system is stable and MYSQL consumes about 30% of CPU according to TOP. During some hours memory consuming is growing but not really quickly. But over time, when MYSQL starts consuming 10GB of RAM it starts over-loading CPU to about 500%. In process list I typically see a lot of slow connections.

How can I tune the database?

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: And post last 400 lines of your Slow Query Log, please, for analysis.

Comment: Rebooting cuts back on memory usage.  High CPU means inefficient queries.  High I/O might mean poor configuration or poor queries.  Get the slowlog.

Comment: Thank you all, fixed by optimizing some slow queries, and reduced database calls from some parts of the site. Also mysqltuner.pl helped to adjust some variables.

Comment: Congratulations.  For workload analysis, post Additional information requested, we can reduce WAIT times for you.